# Python pandas setting NaN values fails

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to clean a dataset in pandas, information is stored ona csv file and is imported using:

```
tester = pd.read_csv('date.csv')
```

Every column contains a '?' where the value is missing. For example there is an age column that contains 9 question marks (?)

I am trying to set the all the question marks to NaN, i have tried:

```
tester = pd.read_csv('date.csv', na_values=["?"])

tester['age'].replace("?", np.NaN)

tester.replace('?', np.NaN)


for col in tester :
    print tester[col].value_counts(dropna=False)
```

Still returns 0 for the age when I know there is 9 (?s). In this case I assume the check is failing as the value is never seen as being ?.

I have looked at the csv file in notepage and there is no space etc around the character.

Is there anyway of forcing this so that it is recognised?

sample data:
[image]

Comment: If `tester = pd.read_csv('date.csv', na_values=["?"])` not working it seems some data related issue

Comment: I there are trailing whitespaces, `tester = pd.read_csv('date.csv', na_values=["?"], skipinitialspace=True)` should help... The best is check data in some editor like notepad++

Comment: since there can be multiple '??' use data['A'].apply(lambda x: x if '?' not in x else 'NaN' )

Comment: @jezrael I have opened this in np++ and there is no characters, record 11, age is first column = ?,100,1.015,2  I have tried skip skipinitialspace=True but madeno difference

Comment: Then no idea... If data are not confidental, you can share it

Comment: @TJ15,  can you try ..  `pd.read_csv('file', sep=', ' , engine='python') ` as there looks to be spaces after comma in the file as i face similar problem and that worked

Comment: @pygo Thanks but when I try that I get "Expected 1 fields in line 32, saw 2. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used."

Comment: @jezrael Don't think I can upload the csv to here but tried to dump some into the description

Comment: @TJ15 - I think it is problem without data, here is necessary convert your data to gdocs, dropbox or similar, because from picture it is not possible see your problem.

Comment: what if you try like : `tester = tester[~(tester == '?').any(axis=1)]`   across the rows where any value is ?

Answer (score 0):

`read_csv` had a `na_values` parameter. See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

```
df = pd.read_csv('date.csv', na_values='?')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very near:

```
# IT looks like file is having spaces after comma, so use `sep`
tester = pd.read_csv('date.csv', sep=', ', engine='python')

tester['age'].replace('?', np.nan)
```

There seems problem with data somewhere so,  for debug..

```
pd.read_csv('file', error_bad_lines=False)

tester = tester [~(tester == '?').any(axis=1)]
```

OR

```
 pd.read_csv('file', sep='delimiter', header=None)
```

OR

```
pd.read_csv('file',header=None,sep=', ')
```